# systemd-resolved needs to be restarted each time after rebooting

Tags: networking, network-manager, systemd-resolved

I've installed dnscrypt-proxy a while ago and modified my `resolv.conf` and `systemctl` settings. Then it stopped working with my internet, so I've removed it.
I tried to get back to old settings, but they vanish each time I reboot Ubuntu. 
Now I have to run these 3 commands each time to make my internet connection working again:

```
 nano /etc/resolv.conf 

 //To set "nameserver 127.0.0.53"

 systemctl restart systemd-resolved.service

 sudo service network-manager restart
```

What can I do to fix it for good?

Answer (score 1):

If you like to set the nameserver to 127.0.0.53 permanently, then try this:

```
(1) sudo nano /etc/systemd/resolved.conf

and add:

[Resolve]
DNS=127.0.0.53
```

```
(2) sudo nano /etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf

and add:

supersede domain-name-servers 127.0.0.53;
```

(3)

```
(A) Click on NetworkManager icon in the system tray 
> Edit connections
> Select the connection you like to edit, e.g.: 'Wired connection 1'
> Click the "Gear" icon to edit the connection
> IPv4 settings
> Method
> Select "Automatic (DHCP) addresses only"
> in the "DNS Servers" field (enter): 127.0.0.53
> Save
```

OR

```
(B) Find out the connection name from Network Manager, e.g.: 'Wired connection 1'

sudo nano '/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/Wired connection 1.nmconnection'

and add:

[ipv4]
dns=127.0.0.53;
dns-search=
ignore-auto-dns=true
method=auto
```

Save, reboot and check (1) `/etc/resolv.conf` what nameserver is in there, and (2) `ping askubuntu.com` to check the Internet connectivity.