# Systemd-networkd has to be manually restarted each boot

Tags: boot, server, systemd-networkd

I need to restart `systemd-networkd` each time I reboot my server.

It fails to start each boot and the status of the service after boot is this as follows. If I restart the service once booted it works just fine.

```
● systemd-networkd.service - Network Service
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-12-22 17:31:27 CET; 1min 2s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-networkd.service(8)
  Process: 1062 ExecStart=/lib/systemd/systemd-networkd (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1062 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
   Status: "Shutting down..."

Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Service has no hold-off time, scheduling restart.
Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: Stopped Network Service.
Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: systemd-networkd.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Dec 22 17:31:27 netcube_ubuntu systemd[1]: Failed to start Network Service.
```

The failures on boot:
[image]

I've tried googling my way to any sort of answers but I cannot find anything relevant... This happened from nowhere. The server has been running fine and after todays scheduled restart this occurs.

Anyone here that can help me with what could be wrong/how to troubleshoot it?

Comment: is this helpfull? https://serverfault.com/questions/745854/cant-get-systemd-networkd-to-start-successfully

Answer (score 1):

### Option 1

Check other possible internet connections in your system.
Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/507225/have-to-restart-network-service-after-reboot-centos-7

### Option 2

Try setting up a wait for the service to be started.
That is, in `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service`, add or append to

```
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```

and reboot.

Partial source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54300998/2707864

### Option 3

Change restart interval. Look for `/etc/systemd/system.conf`
and change

```
#DefaultStartLimitIntervalSec=10s              
#DefaultStartLimitBurst=5
```

to higher values.
A more customized change is possible in other files like `/lib/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service`, with parameters

```
RestartSec=...
StartLimitIntervalSec=...
StartLimitBurst=...
```

Partial sources: https://serverfault.com/a/845473/326962, `man systemd.service`

**Related**:

1. https://forum.level1techs.com/t/ubuntu-need-to-manually-restart-resolved/144081/6
2. [systemd-resolved needs to be restarted each time after rebooting](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1175685/systemd-resolved-needs-to-be-restarted-each-time-after-rebooting)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805354/systemd-start-service-at-boot-time-after-network-is-really-up-for-wol-purpose
4. https://serverfault.com/questions/845471/service-start-request-repeated-too-quickly-refusing-to-start-limit

Comment: Theres only a single cable connected to the server, and The wait service isnt working. (Also shown on the boot errors)

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström - Please see updated answer

Comment: I am not able to test this until a few days since I'm away from the server location. However a very well written response. Will take a look ASAP!

Comment: Still have not been able to test. But gave bounty for well explained response guiding me in some directions. Will mark this as solution if it works when tested!

Comment: None of these options worked, sadly. The current errors in `systemd-networkd.service` are: `Job systemd-networkd-wait-online.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle...`

Comment: @JonathanÖhrström - I suggest you post an edit to the OP with the complete description of what you did, and the present problem.
https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=7993.0
and
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1600823
might be informative.

Answer (score 0):

As answered above I would create a dependency to systemd-networkd-wait-online, but not in the system file /lib/....., instead create a file (and a directory)

```
/etc/systemd/system/systemd-networkd.service.d/override.conf
```

and put the content there instead

```
[Unit]
After=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
Wants=systemd-networkd-wait-online.service
```